# Calculate Longest Consecutive Sequence Across Columns in a Data Frame - R

Tags: r, sequence, intervals

I have a data frame like the one below...

```
df <- data.frame(B1994 = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
                 B1995 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                 B1996 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                 B1997 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                 B1998 = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
)
```

I am now trying to calculate the longest consecutive sequence of 0's across all of the columns (for each row) in this data frame, and populate a new column with these values, like this data frame below...

```
df2 <- data.frame(B1994 = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
                 B1995 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                 B1996 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                 B1997 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                 B1998 = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),
                 Longest_0_Interval = c(1,3,1,5,3,1,1,1,1,3)
)
```

Is there an easy solution for this in R?

Comment: Have a look at the function `rle()`.

Comment: `df$Longest_0_Interval <- apply(as.matrix(df), 1, function(x) {rl <- rle(x); max(rl$lengths[rl$values == 0]) })`

Comment: this is a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`. `matrix` and `data.frame` objects are very different.

Comment: @bcarlsen I made sure to make this adjustment in the question title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rle()`

```
df <- data.frame(B1994 = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
                 B1995 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0),
                 B1996 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0),
                 B1997 = c(1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                 B1998 = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)
)

maxl0 <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  i0 <- which(r$values==0)  ## or i0 <- r$values==0
  max(r$lengths[i0])
}

df$Longest_0_Interval <- apply(df, 1, maxl0)
```

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(Longest_0_Interval = with(rle(c_across(everything())), max(lengths[values == 0])))

   B1994 B1995 B1996 B1997 B1998 Longest_0_Interval
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>              <int>
 1     1     1     0     1     1                  1
 2     0     1     0     0     0                  3
 3     0     1     0     1     0                  1
 4     0     0     0     0     0                  5
 5     1     0     0     0     1                  3
 6     0     1     0     1     0                  1
 7     0     1     1     0     1                  1
 8     1     1     1     1     0                  1
 9     1     0     1     1     0                  1
10     0     0     0     1     1                  3
```